# Filter dataset based on values existing in another data frame

Tags: r

I have simplified the two datafrfames:

```
a = data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
b = data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "6", "7", "8", "8", "3"))
```

How do I filter data frame b with the matching values in a so only the values of 1:5 will remain in b? So only 1, 1, and 3 will remain in b?

Comment: Try `b[b$ID %in% a$ID, , drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using *merge* or an *inner join*. Here are different approaches:

#### Base R

```
merge(a, b)
```

> ```
>   ID
> 1  1
> 2  1
> 3  3
> ```

#### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(a, b)
```

#### `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[setDT(b), on = "ID", nomatch = 0L]
```

Comment: Why post an answer to an obvious duplicate post?